# Is using an undeclared variable legal in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates

*Note: The original problem heavily uses macros, but it has been simplified for this question.*

### The question

```
// header.hpp
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
   someBoolean = true ; // at this point "someBoolean" wasn't
}                       // declared
```

Then, it is used in the following source:

```
// source.cpp
#include "header.hpp"

static bool someBoolean = false ;

void bar()
{
   foo<char>() ; // here, we call/instantiate the function
}
```

In some compilers (Windows, previous Solaris) it works. And in the current C++11 enabled Solaris compiler, it fails, saying someBoolean is undefined.

**According to the standard, can a templated code use a variable that will be (we hope!) declared later in the source?**

### The bonus question

The template is defined in a header that is expected to be included in multiple sources, each one having its own boolean variable, and instantiating the template.

It was expected, in each translation unit, the template would affect the static boolean variable of that translation unit.

Each instantiation of the template on one type (say "char") is thus expected to affect different variables.

**Aren't we relying on undefined behavior, there?**

Comment: "It was expected, in each translation unit, the template would affect the static boolean variable of that translation unit."  This expectation is fallacious.  Even on Windows with the broken two-phase lookup, you aren't guaranteed that.

Comment: Here's what still breaks even if you ignore two-phase lookup:  "A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units.  **If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization diﬀerent meanings according to the one
deﬁnition rule (3.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.**"

Comment: @BenVoigt: You should write a real answer with the full quotes, instead of comments. I would be able to upvote and select it... :-)

Comment: I don't have time :(  Someone else is welcome to do that though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This has to do with two-phase lookup. The short version is that any names that do *not* depend on the template parameter (like `someBoolean` here) will be looked up at template definition time. That means that the Solaris compiler is correct in rejecting the code. `someBoolean` has not been defined before the template is defined.

Names that do depend on the template parameter (e.g. if you had written something like `T::someBoolean = true`) will be deferred to template instantiation time - very reasonably, since their validity can't be determined until the compiler knows what `T` is. MSVC is known for not implementing these two-phase semantics properly (at least historically), which is why your code works there. It is not correct C++ and not portable behaviour, though.

Section 14.6 of (unknown version of) the C++ standard (probably draft):

> If a name does not depend on a template-parameter (as deﬁned in 14.6.2), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template deﬁnition; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations) found at that point and this binding is not aﬀected by declarations that are visible at the point of instantiation.

(via @BenVoigt comment below)

Comment: Here's the exact wording, section 14.6, that creates this behavior: "If a name does not depend on a template-parameter (as deﬁned in 14.6.2), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template deﬁnition; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations) found at that point and this binding is not aﬀected by declarations that are visible at the point of instantiation. "

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have time to look up the legalese for it.

Comment: Both draft n3485 and n4296 contain the same language, which I believe makes this the C++14 version.

Comment: Bonus info: The C++98 standard says the same, at 14.6.2/9 (instead of 14.6.2/10 in the C++14 standard), so this is not a new thing, and applies to some of our (old) compilers.